# Display all characters from API across multiple pages in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch-api

I'm a total beginner in programming and I'm trying to build a react app displaying all Rick and Morty characters using this API:

[https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character?page=${pages}](https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character?page=$%7Bpages%7D)

Using fetch, I was only able to get the first 20 characters. This is my code:

```
    fetch("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setCharacters(data.results));
  }, []);
```

I tried using axios but it won't show up in my package.json.

I would also really like to make functions mapping over the characters and building buttons that filter them by species and gender.

```
const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([]);
  return (
    <div>
      {character.filter(character => character.gender = "Male").map(filteredCharacter => (
        <li>
          {filteredCharacter.gender}
        </li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm getting a ton of errors. Help me?

Answer (score 0):

This API returns *paginated data*, which means it will only return part of the result, and you have to make multiple requests to fetch the entire data set. Each request returns one *page* of data.

After fetching that URL, I used `console.log(data)` to see what the object looked like, and I saw something like this:

```
{
 info: {
   count: 671,
   pages: 34,
   next: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character?page=2",
   prev: null
 },
 results: [
   { id: 1, name: "Rick Sanchez", ... },
   { id: 2, name: "Morty Smith", ... },
   ...
 ]
}
```

This is saying there are 671 characters in total, and there are 34 pages. It also gives you a URL to get the next page.

The simplest algorithm for handling this looks something like this:

1. Fetch the first page, and see if `info.next` has a URL.
2. If it does, then fetch it.
3. Repeat until a page has `null` for `info.next`.
4. Combine the `results` arrays from all the pages.

Doing this well is a little complex, and this algorithm can be made a lot better. If you're still learning, I would just pretend there are only 20 characters, and continue building more of your app.

When you do want to learn to fetch the whole data set, you could try fetching in a loop. There are a few problems you might run into, and solving each of them has varying difficulty:

- The UI might not show anything until all 34 requests are completed
- The UI might show the pages of data as they're fetched, but the page will jump around.
- If you use the component multiple times in your app, you might make the 34 requests every time the component is used.
- If you refresh the page, you might make all 34 requests again.
- After you've fetched the data, you might want to refresh it because you know that a character's biography has been updated.

Since this is a common thing to do, there's a library called [React Query, which provides a hook for fetching paginated data like this](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/paginated-queries). It solves a lot of these problems, but it isn't completely straightforward to use if you aren't yet comfortable with React in general.

Comment: Thank you for answering, now I know about pagination and you've given me two new ideas to try and fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch all data and then add it to your state:

```
const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character");
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async (url) => {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const data = await res.json();
    setCharacters((_characters) => {
      return [..._characters, ...data.results];
    });
    if (data.info && data.info.next) {
      fetchData(data.info.next);
    }
  };
```